Extra unknown display is showing up
I've got a Dell Latitude 7410 running on 24.04. I've had this problem since I went from Windows to Linux, same thing on Ubuntu 22.04, 23.10, 24.04 and I also tested LMDE 6 with the same results.
In my display settings there's always an extra display called "Unknown display" set to a resolution of 640x480. It doesn't matter if I have a second display connected or not.
Display settings:

The unknown display:

When I have a second monitor connected I'm able to turn off this display, but I can't do this when I only use the built-in screen. This sometimes causes apps to hide in the Unknown Display. The solution I do then is to change display settings to only use a single display.
Does anyone have a solution for this? I've been searching for months now.
Display in xrandr:
DP-1 connected 640x480+5360+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm

CPU: Intel i7-10610U (8) @ 4.900GHz
GPU: Intel Comet Lake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]

Interesting...  I recently upgraded to 24.04 and started seeing this extra display.  I have never seen it before with any earlier version.  I haven't been actively trying to find a solution.

Same problem here, it has an Unknown Display at the same resolution you mention and it's a custom machine that ran 23.10 fine. Now I get this second display and cannot go full screen like I did before. The solution is to reinstall 23.10, this version is simply not ready...

Does this answer your question? "Could not switch the monitor configuration" on "None-1-1 connected output"

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516532/how-do-disable-get-rid-of-prime-display This one worked for me

I also have a mysterious "Unknown Display" (in addition to my actual display) on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, with a single monitor connected via DisplayPort (on a desktop computer, i.e. no built-in display).

This question is similar to: How do I disable/get rid of PRIME (None-1-1) display?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Disable simpledrm with kernel parameter "Could not switch the monitor configuration" on "None-1-1 connected output"
There is video about simpledrm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laFx6RQ3XJ4 (source)
This also worked for me, to disable this extra display with xorg, but kernel parameter seems better How do disable/get rid of PRIME display?

Yoga 14 Pro 7 Ultra 9 here with Intel Arc GPU
Only thing that worked for me to remove Unknown 38" display was grub update
From here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2060268/comments/32
From this bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2060268
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

add "initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init" to where it says
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash", so it looks like this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init”
ctrl+O for save and ctrl+X for quit. Back in the terminal write:
sudo update-grub

reboot
PLEASE BE WARNED... This kills my full disk encryption input request on boot.
When i boot i have to count to ten, then blindly type the encryption key and it boots fine. This is a side effect of the work around triggering another bug i think.
Boots fine just no full disk encryption prompt on screen.
The problem looks to be with simpledrm creating a virtual monitor.
if you dont like no encryption prompt, return the grub line back to what it was and update grub again.
