How do I disable/get rid of PRIME (None-1-1) display?
I installed newest cinnamon 24.04, and while in previous version everything worked just fine, in this version I have a 'ghost monitor', to which the cursor can wander, but which cannot be turned off in Display settings.
If I open nvidia settings, I see this:

So there is some prime display, which cannot be controlled. I tried a recommendation to add a kernel parameter
initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init

but this just makes the OS unbootable.
I guess this was induced by upgrading lenovo firmware, which I probably can downgrade back. But is there any better solution? How to get rid of this PRIME display, which is rather sub-prime, since it does not display anything and just makes your work harder.

Adding kernel parameter this way worked for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509661/could-not-switch-the-monitor-configuration-on-none-1-1-connected-output/1514074#1514074

I also have a mysterious "Unknown Display" (in addition to my actual display) on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with an nvidia graphics card, with a single monitor connected via DisplayPort (on a desktop computer, i.e. no built-in display).

The work around can be found in @
maarallez's answer in this Reddit thread: Weird second display: nvidia PRIME Display  (some formatting added by me):

You can disable the ghost screen by writing a short config file.
First, open a terminal and run xrandr to identify your screens. Take note of the name of the ghost device (e.g. HDMI-0, DP-0, etc.); mine was None-1-1.
Then create your config file:
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf

Paste the following, making sure to replace the VGA1 with the name you identified in the previous step:
Section "Monitor"
Identifier "VGA1"
Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection

Save the file and reboot.


Happened to me as well after upgrading to cinammon 24.04, and this fix worked for me as well and interestingly was also called None-1-1

If it re-appears, as it probably will, re-check the configuration file: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf For me it was deleted during updates, so that I can enjoy unusable invisible annoying fake monitor again :)

Thanks. This solution worked for me on a desktop computer running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with an nvidia graphics card, with a single monitor connected via DisplayPort.

Correct me if I am wrong, but 24.04 uses Wayland. This solution assumes X11. Any ideas how to achieve the same thing on Wayland?
