Display Driver issues Nvidia GT 710

I am using a single display, but my display settings are showing a multiple display option. When I start my PC, it automatically goes into dual display mode. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Disable the extra displays in the display config.

You are probably seeing a ghost prime display a solution is here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516532/how-do-disable-get-rid-of-prime-display/1516571#1516571
