Disable external monitor while in login screen Ubuntu 24.04
As the title, my login background is split into 2 (1 horizontal and 1 vertical) while I'm on the login screen.
Are there any solutions to temporarily disable the vertical monitor and then re-enable it after logging in?
I check the vertical with xrandr and it seems it is the DP-2
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7424 x 4096, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 2304x4096+0+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95 + 144.01*  120.00    99.95
   1920x1080    119.88   100.00    60.00    59.94    50.00
   1440x900      59.89
   1440x576      50.00
   1440x480      59.94
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x720      59.94    50.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 5120x2880+2304+549 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   2560x1440    164.96*+ 143.97   120.00    99.95    59.95
   1920x1080    119.88   100.00    60.00    59.94    50.00
   1280x720      59.94    50.00
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       59.94    59.93
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
None-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768      60.00 +

I tried to disable it with xrandr --output DP-2 --auto but it did not work.

Hi I am not able to help on the issue but if the background positions are the main issue you can try an extension for gdm login screen.

@PRATAP can you recommend me some extensions for that? I'm using GDM setting app but it seems to lack some of the options compared to the guide I found on other forums

Yes sure, but before suggesting I would like to know do you have some knowledge about command line and make file?

Here is the extension https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/gdm-extension

I guess if you have the background image for your vertical monitor the same ratio then it should display properly with this extensioin.

To disable None-1-1 see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516532/how-do-disable-get-rid-of-prime-none-1-1-display/1516571#1516571

@PRATAP it's working perfectly now!!!

With the above link None-1-1 or gdm-extension?

The gdm-extension works well
